# JSON isn't posting correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, post

So I'm trying to add an object with a bunch of attributes inside of it.

This is the object I'm trying to $.post

```
({"fname" : fname,
          "lname" : lname,
          "gender" : gender,
          "traits" : {
          "iq" : intellect,
          "height" : height,
          "speed" : speed,
          "weight" : weight,
          "stamina" : stamina,
          "toughness" : toughness
          },
          "homeState" : homeState,
          "country" : country
         });
```

Prior to posting the object, everything works fine. I can do `obj.traits.iq` and it will return the exact iq needed, etc. looking at the inspector, "traits" comes up as an Object.

The problem starts once I post it with this function

```
$.post( url, obj, function(data){
console.log(data);})
}
```

The object gets posted and I can access it, but it's formatting is all weird. 
Instead of traits showing as `"traits": Object;` 
it shows as `traits[iq]: 100, traits[height]: 5'6` ,, etc. Rather than showing up as an acccessible object, it just automatically shows all traits in that format. What am I doing wrong? I don't even know what to look up, or why it's happening.

The problem this causes is that there are other objects in the API that return correctly, where their "traits" shows up as `"traits":object`, rather than `traits[iq]: 100 traits[height]: 5'6`, etc. This causes all of the functionality I have written around the API to not work on any new object that I add.

API Info:

Example request

```
POST /apikey/players HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Host: --------

{
    "fname": "Steve",
    "lname": "Harley",
    ...
}
```

Example Response: the post is supposed to return the object with a new id property

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 10 SEPT 2014 12:24:28 GMT

{
    "id": 11,
    "fname": "Steve",
    "lname": "Harley",
        ...
}
```

Comment: How are you reading the posted data, lets see some code.

Comment: Please Show us the server side code for this post call

Comment: Ah, yeah - problem is that I don't control the server side code. It's not my API, do you think the error is on their end?

Comment: Does the api have any documentation?

Comment: That's the correct serialization, if you want the PHP-backend to parse it (out of the box). First of all, I don't really understand wether you mean the data you send to the backend or the data you get from the backend is messed up. Then, what input does the backend expect?

Comment: Edited some API docs into the post

Comment: Backend expects you to send it a player object, and it adds the player object into it's database and returns it to you with an ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the api expects json, which is not what you're sending.
To send json you have to encode the data to json and se

```
$.post( {
    url: url, 
    data: JSON.stringify(obj), 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some API can send us the response in diferent formats depending on which format we have specified at the request (this type of API can be easily done with ASP.NET for example). Have you tried to explicit specify the *dataType* parameter as **json**, like this?

```
$.post(url, obj, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
}, "json");
```